# React: Function in Component to calculate Reward points not working

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm trying to code a function in the RewardsCard Component to calculate how much reward points a customer receive for his purchase. However, there were some errors and I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

this is the Purchase Month Component that calls RewardsCard in its code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RewardsCard from "./RewardsCard";

export default class purchaseMonth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        transitionArr: this.props.transitions
    };
  }

  render() {
    const transitionList = this.state.transitionArr;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.month}</h2>
        <div>
        {transitionList.map((eachTransition, i) => (
          <RewardsCard
          {...eachTransition}
          key={eachTransition.id}
          purchased={eachTransition.purchase}
          />
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And there's the RewardsCard itself

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class RewardsCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        purchaseN: this.props.purchased,
        rewards1: 0,
        rewards2: 0
    };
  }

  calculateRewards = () => {
    // console.log("purchasereward", this.state.purchaseN);
    let purchasedT = this.props.purchased;
    if(50 < purchasedT && purchasedT < 100) {
      let getRewards1 = purchasedT - 50;
      this.setState ({
        rewards1: getRewards1
      })
    }
    if(purchasedT > 100) {
      let getRewards2 = (purchasedT - 100) * 2;
      this.setState({
        rewards2: getRewards2
      })
    }
    let totalRewards = this.state.rewards1 + this.state.rewards2
    return totalRewards;
  }

  render() {    

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.date}</p>
        <p>{this.props.purchase}</p>
        <p>{this.calculateRewards()}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The error I got is `"Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within` render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning states you are setting the state inside the render function.

From your code, you dont need to set the state, you can calculate the value and return it which will be shown in render.

You can change the calcualteRewards function like below

```
  calculateRewards = () => {
    // console.log("purchasereward", this.state.purchaseN);
    let purchasedT = this.props.purchased;
    let totalRewards = 0;
    if(50 < purchasedT && purchasedT < 100) {
      let getRewards1 = purchasedT - 50;
        totalRewards += getRewards1;
    }
    if(purchasedT > 100) {
      let getRewards2 = (purchasedT - 100) * 2;
      totalRewards += getRewards2;
    }

    return totalRewards;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain what is wrong is the calculateRewards() function. Having it in the component goes against react. Here is an example of it that *should* work

```
export default class RewardsCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        purchaseN: this.props.purchased,
        rewards1: 0,
        rewards2: 0
    };
  }

  calculateRewards = () => {
    // console.log("purchasereward", this.state.purchaseN);
    let purchasedT = this.props.purchased;
    if(50 < purchasedT && purchasedT < 100) {
      let getRewards1 = purchasedT - 50;
      this.setState ({
        rewards1: getRewards1
      })
    }
    if(purchasedT > 100) {
      let getRewards2 = (purchasedT - 100) * 2;
      this.setState({
        rewards2: getRewards2
      })
    }
    let totalRewards = this.state.rewards1 + this.state.rewards2
    return totalRewards;
  }
  let rewards = calculateRewards();
  render() {    

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.date}</p>
        <p>{this.props.purchase}</p>
        <p>{rewards}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```